# Use office 365 login/credentials as Single Sign On

Tags: azure, office365

Can I use office 365 login/credentials as Single Sign On? Actually I need to sign in my web application using office 365 login details.

Further I want to use following url credentials for Single Sign On in my web application.
https://portal.office.com

Answer (score 5):

Indeed. Office365 identities are backed by Azure Active Directory, and you can build WebApps, WebAPIs and mobile apps secured using Azure Active Directory, so that customers of Offic365 can SSO to your applications.

The various auth scenarios supported by Azure AD are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn499820.aspx. Code samples are here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn646737.aspx.

Hope that helps.