# PHP application, SAML and single sign-on with office 365

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, saml, office365

How to make possible single sign-in into my php app for Office 365 users?
I was reading a bit about Microsoft solutions and if I understood well I have to create account on Microsoft Azure AD and buy their services, right?
I found out that Azure AD supports SAML 2.0..
Does anyone did this before and can describe a process a bit more detailed for me? && what data I am receving in SAML response? =)

I am already familiar with SAML protocol and using it.. just not with Microsoft services and where to go to complete this..

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

After whole day of digging found something:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-php-web-single-sign-on/

I hope it will be useful for others who have similar question ;-)

Comment: You might want to check this: https://auth0.com/authenticate/php/azure-ad which is way simpler. (Disclaimer: I work for Auth0).

Comment: but this is logging with Azure AD not with Office 365... or I am dump and I can log into Azure with Office 365 credentials? =P

Comment: Office 365 is in essence Azure AD (the identity part)

Comment: the answer on my doubts others can find here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198313/use-office-365-login-credentials-as-single-sign-on?rq=1

Comment: Dead link in answer.